# Attempt to change component state security exception in android

Tags: java, android, permissions

hi i am working in framework side implementing one test app to disable another app but when i run my test app it is showing

```
Java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=xxx,uid=xxxx,package uid=xxx
at xxxxxxxx
```

my java code

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackagemanager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.example","MainActivity"),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE>
```

i have tried above permission with both (Permission is only granted to system apps) and also tried  tag but no lucky

how to use system apps granted permission,

Could you please guys help me to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you application is not a  part of the system partition, then you will not be granted the permission. Get the app into the system partition and confirm that the PackageManager upon parsing your app during the dexopt grants you your desired permission.

Comment: i had pushed apk to system and tied but no luch when i analyze the devoce log cat i had seen same exception , could you please suggest if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: As I said above, ensure that the PacakageManager is granting you the permission during dexopt.

Answer (score 1):

You can not Enable/disable app unless your app is system app

Answer (score 0):

My steps are:

1. Disable package with command: `pm disable "packageName"`
2. Enable packageName with command: `pm enable packageName`
3. Launch principal activity if you know the name activity principal,

   `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   i.setComponent(new ComponentName("namePackage", "namePackage.MainPrincipal"));
   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   startActivity(i);`

Comment: not it doesnt work that way

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, you can install your app as a system app by simply copying the apk into /system/app (/system/priv-app for 4.4+). This will allow you to use the "system only" permissions.