# hide another application in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to hide another application by using the following code:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.sas.remotesample",".Player"),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and with the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
```

but it throws

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277887/attempt-to-change-component-state-security-exception-in-android

Comment: Thanks but it did not help me to find a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE` has a `protectionLevel` of `signature|privileged`. This means that either:

- You have to build your own custom ROM, then sign your app with the same signing key that you used to sign your custom ROM. Then, devices with your custom ROM installed will allow your app to control component states of other apps.
- Your app has to be pushed to the system partition on rooted devices by their users.

Otherwise, you cannot hold this permission. Or, as [the documentation for the permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE) states, "Not for use by third-party applications".