# How to disable Firebase Messaging on boolean from Shared Preferences (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android development.
I have In App Billing that lets people buy push notifications.

When I implemented Firebase Messaging. It just worked out of the box. Awesome!

But. I now want to disable it if it is not bought. (store boolean in shared preferences)

I have no idea how to approach this.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends     FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
}
```

and

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";



@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

}

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}
}
```

manifest: (inside application tags)

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I have a boolean stored in Shared preferences called "notifications"

Basically my question is:
where do i put

```
if(boolean == true){
// do notification (no clue what this method would be)
}
```

Where and what do I have to look for or do a search for?
Please point me in the right direction :)

Kind regards,

Chris

Comment: where the all notifications are showing disable them according to the status of the notification variable.
I might did't get your problem clearly !

Comment: do you use `notification` or `data` type message ?

Comment: @nightcoder. the problem is that i don't know where the showing of notification is being called.

Comment: @Wilik, I don't use anything specific

Comment: so you send the notification via the firebase console? if you send it via the API, the request should contain a notification and/or data payload. Both of them behave differently.

Comment: yes it is firebase console

Answer (score 5):

You can disable whole service, to simplify your code

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And after user purchase - enable it

```
PackageManager pm  = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
    componentName,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
);
```

This approach will also conserve battery life, because app won't be launched when push received.

Comment: Thanks, going to give this a shot. nice to safe battery aswell

Comment: Can i activate this just once? @Dima

Comment: @Chrizlee yes, it will remain active

Comment: I don't know why but this crash my application without any logcat

Comment: Are you sure this is working? As i ran into the `Java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state ...`
Exception
https://stackoverflow.com/q/22277887/8524651

Comment: It is working fine, but it is important to pass the proper context. InstrumentationContext will lead to that error while activity context is working fine even within the tests

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // check condition pay or not
    if(CheckCondition){
       // if user pay/bought product
       sendPushNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
      }
    else{
     // else user not pay/bought product
    // do not show Push to user
      }     
    }

   private void sendNotification(String messageBody)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("msg",messageBody);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I will give it a shot.

where does the sendPushNotification() method come from?

That function made no sense to me, since there was no actual function call inside. ( i thought they only log the getBody() )

Comment: Yeah the check condition is clear. I need to find out how to make this notification appear now

because without that function it already showed the notification

It already sent the notifications with the code i provided in the question :o

Comment: check my updated answer. i have added that function to show Push notif

Comment: I'm not sure about this solution, if the user or the task manager kills the app the variable "CheckCondition" no longer exist. This mean that you won't be able to receive notification until he restart the app.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion for this is to create a topic and automatically subscribe the user to that topic straight based on your boolean value:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

unsubscribe from the topic.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");
```

This will remove them from the list on the server, and you wont be relying on client side logic to filter out unwanted notifications.

Hope it's help you.