# How to hide other application's icon from my app

Tags: android

I am making an application. My application gets all the installed applications. What I want is to hide app icons of some selected apps. For hiding app icon I am using below code and that is working as expected.

```
 public void hideApp(String className) {
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, className);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

**Note: I am sending class name with complete pkg name. And this is hiding my app icon perfectly**.

But when I try to hide other app icon with complete pakage name is gives exception as mentioned below

```
IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.whatsapp.Main does not exist in com.example.abdulwaheed.testingproject
```

My question is what am I doing wrong? As I missing anything? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've not had experience with this, but I can at least try to point you in the right direction.

I think the problem is in this line:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, className);
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html),

> Two pieces of information, encapsulated here, are required to identify a component: the package (a String) it exists in, and the class (a String) name inside of that package.

So instead of "this", which refers to your activity, you actually need the package name of the application you're trying to hide. Then, you'd put in their className for the second variable.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives below exception 
SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state

Comment: That is an intentional effect of the Android operating system; your application must be a system app to change component state (meaning that your application would have to be Targeted at rooted users who can sideload your app as a system application). Here's another answer that expounds on that a little: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22277945/7612525